# How to get the ID of the element that my tag <img> is in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to get the ID of

```
<table id="table">
<th>Name</th>
<tr><td id="td1"><img id="img1"onload="getData(this)" aref and so on></td></tr>`
</table>
```

I need to get that  ID.. For my function getData(this)

```
            alert($(this).parent().attr('ID'));
            alert(($(this).closest("TD").find('ID')));
            alert($idd.closest('td').attr('id'));
            alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
```

Tried this ones but no succses get undefined in alert.

I need to make the function dynamic so it can take any element.

instead of this

```
document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML = data;
document.getElementById('td2').innerHTML = data;
```

i want to pass a variable to the

```
document.getElementById(VAR).innerHTML = data
```

data is a ajax call.

IT dosent matter if its done with JSor jquery :) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSFiddle, It's pretty !

You have two errors :

- `$.ready` not need to be use in function
- You use `getApi(this)`, but you need to use `getApi($(this))`

You must do that :

```
function getApi(idd) {
    $.ajax({
        .....
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vryymy8p/24/

Comment: Thx Thomas ur the best!! Great help u are the king

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$(this).attr('id'); // img1
$(this).parent('td').attr('id'); // td1
$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').parent('table').attr('id'); // table
```

I hope it's your question because I'm french...

Comment: I still get undefined when i echo the answer $(this).parent('td').attr('id');

so weird

Answer (score 0):

I thinks your html is wrong :

http://jsfiddle.net/vryymy8p/2/

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">
            <img id="img1" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="background:#000" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works, i have found out thatthis is not the problem with the unndefined.. im doing somehing else wrrong

Comment: This is the result
http://piclair.com/nrmqy

My function
http://piclair.com/4rj1q

I cant get the id with IDD i send into the metod?